# Dose PE Explorer unpack upx executables?

Tags: static-analysis, unpacking, packers, upx

I was analysing Lab01-02.exe from Practical Malware Analysis book, the exe is packed with upx, since it showed UPX0, 1, 2 in the header section when analyzed with PEview, but when I open the same exe with PE Explorer is showed the regular header section (.txt .data ... )
Dose PE Explorer unpack packed files before analyze it? what if I want to view the packed exe with PE Explorer?

Comment: Use another software? PEview or CFF Explorer come to mind

Comment: PE Explorer ships with the UPX Unpacker plug-in see this http://www.heaventools.com/PE_Explorer_plug-ins.htm, to disable the UPX Unpacker plug-in  from the Tools menu Select Plug-in Manager, now Select UPX Unpacker plug-in and set the value to zero to  disables the plug-in and marks it red.

Comment: @Dillinur: Thanx, I don't know CFF, but I'll give it a try

Comment: @adrián Perfect, why u didn't post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [product overview of PE Explorer](http://www.heaventools.com/overview.htm) states in several places that it will load PE files that are compressed with UPX.

> Open UPX-, Upack- and NsPack-compressed files seamlessly in PE Explorer, without long workarounds